# Compiling the Latest MonoGame.dll on GitHub

Tags: monogame, source-code, git

I've been searching for hours, but still I cannot find "How to compile the latest MonoGame source code from GitHub".

I have tried cloning the GitHub project (develop branch) and I've been looking for the solution that can be used so it will open on Xamarin studio and compile directly, but I have no luck and I don't know if it is the right procedure to get the latest MonoGame library.

Can anyone please help me cite the steps and procedures needed to compile the latest MonoGame source code from GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to modify any source, I would recommend you instead get a nightly build and use that instead.

**Installing an mpack in Xamarin Studio**

This should be the easiest method to get MonoGame working in Xamarin Studio. Go to the [downloads page](http://www.monogame.net/downloads/) and click on "MonoGame for MonoDevelop".

This will download a .mpack that you can install directly by going to the "AddIn's Manager" in Xamarin Studio. Choose "Install from file" and locate the .mpack and you should be good to go

**Using .dlls from a nightly build**

Go to the [downloads page](http://www.monogame.net/downloads/) and then click on "MonoGame for Visual Studio" under Development Builds. That will get you the latest build from the [MonoGame TeamCity page](http://teamcity.monogame.net/viewType.html?buildTypeId=MonoGame_DevelopWin).

You can then unzip the executable and grab the .dll files which will be in the folder "Assemblies" and use them as references in your Xamarin Studio project.

if you really want to compile it, it's not too bad either.

**Compiling From Source**

Either fork the [MonoGame Develop repository](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop) or download the project as a .zip from GitHub and run ProtoBuild.exe

That will create all of the .csproj files for each platform, which you can open in Xamarin Studio to use as library projects.

Comment: Gotta try this... so much information you have there. Im very thankful, Wow. great. thanks very much :)

Comment: For sure! I forgot that you can also install an mpack, that should be the easiest method, so I updated the answer

Comment: but is it the latest version? i mean even the changes on github gets applied to this?

Comment: yes, the nightly builds from the teamCity links are generated on a daily basis using the develop branch on github. I use these as well, and they contain many fixes not included in the original 3.2 release

Comment: nice. :D thanks for the very informative answer. cheers. :)